# Changing cart data during Ajax woocommerce

Tags: cookies, woocommerce

I'm trying to replace the current WooCommerce cart with a saved one, during Ajax.

This is the code i'm using:

```
function restore()
{
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($current_user_id > 0) {
        if (function_exists('get_user_attribute')) {

            $buy_now_persistent_cart = get_user_meta($current_user_id, '_buy_now_persistent_cart', true);
            error_log(print_r($buy_now_persistent_cart, 1));

        if (!empty($buy_now_persistent_cart['cart'])) {
            WC()->session->cart            = $buy_now_persistent_cart['cart'];
            WC()->session->applied_coupons = $buy_now_persistent_cart['applied_coupons'];
            if (function_exists('delete_user_attribute')) {
                //delete_user_attribute( $current_user_id, '_buy_now_persistent_cart' );
            }
            //delete_user_meta( $current_user_id, '_buy_now_persistent_cart' );
        }
    }
}
```

This is the $buy_now_persistent_cart output:

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [3430dcf4efe8aa0c418434656773a73a] => Array
                (
                    [key] => 3430dcf4efe8aa0c418434656773a73a
                    [product_id] => 126096
                    [variation_id] => 0
                    [variation] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [quantity] => 1
                    [data_hash] => b5c1d5ca8bae6d4896cf1807cdf763f0
                    [line_tax_data] => Array
                        (
                            [subtotal] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [total] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [line_subtotal] => 2.4
                    [line_subtotal_tax] => 0
                    [line_total] => 2.4
                    [line_tax] => 0
                )

        )

    [applied_coupons] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

When I output WC()->session->cart after setting the new data it seems to have changed correctly, but the updated cart is not there when the Ajax finishes.

I guess it is about saving the cart and/or setting a cart hash and cookies?

I just can't figure it out.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it in a different way. First empty the user cart, then add all the products.
Something like:

```
if (!empty($buy_now_persistent_cart['cart'])) {
   WC()->cart->empty_cart();
   foreach($buy_now_persistent_cart['cart'] as $item){
      WC()->cart->add_to_cart($item['product_id'], $item['quantity']);
   }
}
```

I didn't tested it, but in general I think it's a better approach than forcing a session

Comment: Thanks. With your code, I printed the cart contents to the error log during the Ajax - and the cart updated. But after the Ajax returns, when I add other product with Ajax, or reload the page - the cart empties. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a conjunction with another code you are having, Try to look where else you are empty the cart. If nowhere else, maybe try to remove the line of empty_cart() I added, just for the test

Comment: Yes. You are right. Stripe's plugin clears the cart after the hook that I'm using is called. I switched to a later hook and both your code and mine are working. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome, and you can always choose this answer as the correct answer :) thx